# Setting up a linux server to share an internet connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wifi

I in the process of reconfiguring my network. It is currently like this:

```
internet - modem - wireless router - wired server/clients 
                          |
                          |---- wireless clients
```

but I need to move the router to get a better signal for the wireless clients. So, I'm looking at this:

```
internet - modem - server - switch - wired clients
                               |
                               |---- wireless router - wireless clients
```

How do I set up the server to enable this? Also, what set ups do the clients need.

The server is Ubuntu 9.04 and the clients are a mix of Windows XP / 7, Ubuntu and printers.

I believe this new set up will allow me to control access to the internet, which would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of hunting around for information, I stumbled accross a perfect little utility to get the above working - dnsmasq. I uninstalled dhcp3-server and bind9, installed dnsmasq, wrote a two line configuration file (which NIC to use and the DHCP address range to use), rebooted and everything works great.

Now there's no pressure from my users I can take my time and figure out how everything works. I'm not sure how flexible dnsmasq is, but now I can take my time over it.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to configure on linux:

- routing [ packet forwarding ]
- network address translation

to make things easier you might want to also set up on linux also:

- recursive dns server
- dhcp server

look [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/nat-gateway-iptables-port-forwarding-dns-and-dhcp-setup-ubuntu-8.10-server) for those.

when you get profficient you might be interested in traffic shaping to share bandwidth in fair way between the station - google for *linux qos*.

if you have public ip from your ISP you might want to do port forwarding - google for *iptables dnat*.

if you use dhcp - you do not need to configure anything on your windows [or any other system] clients.

Comment: Blimey, there's a lot to this, and not much of it makes sense. I really hate these guides that just throw loads of config files at you without really explaining what's going on.